# I got error when i try to send mail with nodemailer and i'm using cpanel information

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, nodemailer

```
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

require("dotenv").config();

const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.ibendouma.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,

  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER,
    pass: process.env.SECRET,
  },
});


async function run() {
  let sendResult = await smtpTransport
    .sendMail({
      from: "'iBendouma' <service@ibendouma.com>",
      to: "tipox1254@gmail.com",
      subject: "Hello from iBendouma",
      text: "copier le code et verifier votre identité",
    })
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  console.log(sendResult);
}

run().catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

> Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
> at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:787:19)
> at SMTPConnection.login (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:441:38)
> at C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:272:32
> at SMTPConnection. (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:211:17)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
> at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1322:14)
> at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:950:20)
> at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:752:14)
> at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib

msypro@Msypro MINGW64 ~/Desktop/test (master)
$ node app.js
Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:787:19)
at SMTPConnection.login (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:441:38)
at C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:272:32
at SMTPConnection. (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:211:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:400:28)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1322:14)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:950:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:752:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\msypro\Desktop\test\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:191:44) {
code: 'EAUTH',
command: 'API'
}
undefined

Answer (score 0):

This error `Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" at SMTPConnection._formatError` occurs when your credentials are missing. First thing you can do is to check whether the `env` file is specified properly in the code. You have to make sure that your index.js or server.js (or the name of your nodemailer code file) is in the same directory as `env` file.

If the above is all correct then try adding quotes around your `env` variable like below.

```js
auth: {
    user: `${process.env.USER}`,
    pass: `${process.env.SECRET}`,
},
```

Your auth field have to look like this.

```js
auth: {
    user: "someone@gmail.com",
    pass: "somesecretpass",
},
```

Hope this worked!

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work, it gives me the same error.

Comment: thank you it works finally I replaced the environment variable by the email and the password directly at the level of auth.